# Is it better way to do that?

Tags: ruby

I wrote a simple script to sum all digits of positive integer input until 1 digit is left ( for example for input 12345 result is 6 because 1+2+3+4+5 = 15 and 1+5 = 6). It works but is it better way to do that? ( more correct?)

here is a code:

```
def sum(n)
  string=n.to_s
  while string.length > 1 do
    result=string.chars.inject { |sum,n| sum = sum.to_i + n.to_i}
    string=result.to_s
  end
  puts "Sum of digits is " + string 
end

begin
  p "please enter a positive integer number:"
  number = Integer(gets.chomp)
  while number<0
    p "Number must be positive!Enter again:"
    number = Integer(gets.chomp)
  end 
rescue
  p "You didnt enter integer!:"
  retry
end

sum(number)
```

Comment: You really don't see `retry` used much in Ruby so it's interesting to see it used here. Do be careful when doing a blind `rescue`, called a Pokémon Rescue since you "catch them all", because errors in your code will be interpreted as invalid input. Try to scope that down to the errors you're specifically *expecting*. One more thing: Try to use `.to_i` to convert to integer values. Using `Integer` is typically reserved for special cases. Using a regular expression to test input like `number.match(/\A\d+\z/)` would catch all positive numbers, or a lazy test: `number.to_i.to_s == number`.

Answer (score 5):

According to Wikipedia, the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root#Congruence_formula) is:

> dr(*n*) = 1 + ((*n* − 1) mod 9)

So it boils down to:

```
def sum(n)
  1 + (n - 1) % 9
end
```

To account for `0`, you can add `return 0 if n.zero?`

Comment: This is brilliant and shows that when faced with a maths problem, seek out what the maths guys have already come up with.

Comment: I'm curious how you found this, unless you already knew it was the "digital root" or "repeated digital sum" that you were looking for.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I knew the German term ("einstellige Quersumme" which translates to "one-digit cross-sum") and wanted to look up the English one. I wasn't aware of that formula or the [repeating sequence](https://oeis.org/A010888) of the digital root, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`divmod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) (quotient and modulus) to calculate the digit sum without converting to / from string. Something like this should work:

```
def sum(number)
  result = 0
  while number > 0 do
    number, digit = number.divmod(10)
    result += digit
    if number == 0 && result >= 10
      number = result
      result = 0
    end
  end
  result
end

sum(12345) #=> 6
```

The line

```
number, digit = number.divmod(10)
```

basically strips off the last digit:

```
12345.divmod(10) #=> [1234, 5]
```

`1234` becomes the new `number` and `5` is being added to `result`. If `number` eventually becomes zero and `result` is equal or greater than `10` (i.e. more than one digit), `result` becomes the new `number` (e.g. `15`) and the loops starts over. If `result` is below `10` (i.e. one digit), the loop exits and `result` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking good to me. You might do things a little more conscise like use `map` to turn every char into an integer.

```
def sum(n)
  string=n.to_s
  while string.length > 1 do
    result = string.chars.map(&:to_i).inject(&:+)
    string = result.to_s
  end
  puts "Sum of digits is " + string 
end
```

Comment: Even shorter: `inject(:+)`

Answer (score 1):

Short recursive version:

```
def sum_of_digits(digits)
  sum = digits.chars.map(&:to_i).reduce(&:+).to_s
  sum.size > 1 ? sum_of_digits(sum) : sum
end

p sum_of_digits('12345') #=> "6"
```

Single call version:

```
def sum_of_digits(digits)
  digits = digits.chars.map(&:to_i).reduce(&:+).to_s until digits.size == 1
  return digits
end
```

Comment: Add `to_s` to work for both strings and integers like in the users example. `digits = digits.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).reduce(&:+).to_s until digits.size == 1`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use .digits, so you don't have to convert the input into a string.

```
def digital_root(n)

  while n.digits.count > 1 
    array = n.digits 
    n = array.sum
  end
  return n

end
```